# How would you figure out what's wrong with this meteor project?

Tags: meteor

```
=> Started your app.
=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: ENOMEM, write
```

Nothing more in the console. (running on nitrous.io btw)

**EDIT: it was a dummy out of resource error due to Meteor upgrade**

CLOSED

Comment: think you should learn more JavaScript than meteor to start with. i hope i don't sound like an a hole lols.

Comment: If you use a huge framework, like Meteor, I guess you should learn more Meteor, than javascript IMHO.

Comment: ENOMEM indicates that Meteor process ran out of memory (RAM). Unfortunately right now the Meteor build too is pretty hungry on RAM.

Comment: I simply ran out of resources. These types of events could really cause **ANY** type of errors.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your events.js file, on line 72 seems like a good place to start. If you post some code from that file/line it'll be a lot easier to help you fix it.

Comment: Since meteor immediately crashes, I found no way to gather this generated events.js file.